# How is it possible to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on a Macbook Pro from a microSD Card, or minimal install from CD (not a DVD)?

Tags: dual-boot, macbook

I see tutorials on the internet seeming to do so - including from Ubuntu's site - and people in the comments saying the terrible directions work, but I've tried it all and after a handful of now-useless CD-R's with 40MB of data on them, countless times reformatting and setting up the SD Card, many times using Mac Linux USB Loader, and even trying UNETBootin though I knew it can't make a Mac OS X bootable SD Card I haven't gotten ANY unique results - everything I try does NOTHING. I've even installed rEFInd and the only thing that does is give me a menu when I boot up. The only options in either rEFInd or when booting/restarting with the Option/Alt key held are the standard ones with OS X (boot from Macintosh HD, boot from Recovery HD, blah blah blah) no matter how I do the steps, or what tutorial I follow. Booting with a CD that has the minimal install burned to it didn't do anything either, even after fixing it with the dd command in terminal.

My machine:
Macbook Pro 15" Late 2011 model
Mac OS X 10.9.5
2.4GHz Intel Core i7
4GB 1333 MHz DDR3 RAM
Integrated Graphics: Intel HD 3000 384MB
Discrete Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M 1024MB

A site one of the tutorials pointed me to had my system listed as having a 64-bit EFI, which was important for some reason I cannot remember right now because I am too tired and angry.

The HDD has been partitioned to give Mac 500 GB & Ubuntu 250 GB (formatted to FAT as was directed in multiple tutorials).

I have a 2GB microSD Card to hold the "Live"/full install, connected to my PC via a USB hub; not sure what it's Class is, as it's unmarked, but it came with a phone so likely class 2..but I'm used to waiting for downloads overnight, so I can wait it out.

I have some 700MB CD-R discs to hold the minimal install (almost 40mb..).

I have officially reached my wits end following tutorials online, and am about to take the space on my HDD back and give Ubuntu the finger as Torvalds did to Nvidia.

Has anyone managed to do this (preferably on this same machine), just to know it's possible?
Are there any ACCURATE Ubuntu 14.04.2 Live-CD or minimal install from CD/microSD Card directions?

I want to keep OS X, and would prefer to have the easier full install from Live-CD but am willing to try customizing the minimal install.

Edit: Never did get this to work; gave up after this. Just recovered my account here finally, sorry for the lack of response.

Comment: why can't you use a USB?

Comment: I didn't have one, but have found one since & also discovered that trying to use an SD Card to boot (on Mac) is apparently not even supported (because of Apple, it seemed to be implying). Now using a device that's identified as an iPod & has Shuffle/Repeat switch like an MP3 player, but no screen/wheel..so, 2 GB USB stick I consider it.

Comment: An SD Card cannot be used to boot a Mac, I read somewhere earlier. The USB drive has almost worked (in 2 diff ways), but it fails before loading the OS (i8042: No controller found OR No bootable deviced found error).

I know I'm not far off, somewhere in there, but I have no idea where to go.

Sorry for double-comment..it wouldn't let me edit (was past 5 mins).

Comment: how did you make the live "USB" that you have? Did you use some tool slike UNetbootin?